# GitLab CI CD authenticating issue with ssh-add

Tags: shell-script, gitlab

i was working with gitlab ci cd but unfortunately the error occurred when I access my deployment server and after prompting `ssh-agent` and add my private key with ssh-add it just shows `Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory`. Somehow the `ssh-add` is not being propagated or the `ssh-agent` is not being started. I have configured all the steps on a shell script. It's given below.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get server list 
set -f
string=$DEPLOY_SERVER_IP
array=(${string//,/ })

# Iterate servers for deploy and pull last commit 
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
  echo "Deploy project on server ${array[i]}"
  ssh bitnami@${array[i]} "eval $(ssh-agent -s)\ssh-add relation-fe && cd htdocs/relation-fe/ && git pull"
done
```

The gitlab-ci.yml file contains the following

```
build-job:
  tags:
    - ci
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  tags:
    - ci
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"

test-job2:
  tags:
    - ci
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
    - sleep 20

deploy-prod:
  tags:
    - ci
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - bash .gitlab-deploy-prod.sh
```

The output on my deploy build log.

```
Preparing the "shell" executor
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
Running on ip-172-26-14-215...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/8x1yWQpE/0/root/relation-fe/.git/
Checking out b7d66a8d as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 26162
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ bash .gitlab-deploy-prod.sh
Deploy project on server 1.2.3.4
Agent pid 26167
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Could anyone please help me with this? I'm stuck here for couple of days now. I think the main issue is on this line 
`ssh bitnami@${array[i]} "eval $(ssh-agent -s)\ssh-add relation-fe && cd htdocs/relation-fe/ && git pull"`

Somehow I did something wrong here!!! Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: in the last line `ssh bitnami@${array[i]} "eval $(ssh-agent -s)\ssh-add (...)` 1) `$(ssh-agent -s)` is evaluated localy, is that what you meant ? 2) what is the purpose on `\` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, `eval$(ssh-agent -s)`  is to start the ssh authentication service, after that `ssh-add` adds the private key. Here `relation-fe` is my private key. Well to sum up in this line i need to add the private key to varify my private git repository and pull the latest commit from gitlab. But i can't add the private key and authenticate my private git repository.

Comment: let me repeat. Is `ssh-agent -s`  to be run **localy** or **remotly**. my guess is that you intend to run it on `bitnami@${array[i]}` but this is not the case.

Comment: `ssh-agent` should run remotely on the server, I intend to run it on the `bitnami@${array[i]}` server.